# Javascript image slideshow works locally, but not when hosted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looks like you guys are my go to help for javascript. I have a slideshow that works perfectly when I load the local copy of my webpage. However it does not work when I load the actual page, hosted on GoDaddy. The first image shows, but is just static. Console shows no errors. Once again, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="auto-style1" style="width: 226px; height: 179px">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

        // LIST OF IMAGES 
        path[0] = "images/image_1.png"; 
        path[1] = "images/image_2.png"; 
        path[2] = "images/image_3.png";
        path[3] = "images/image_4.png";
        path[4] = "images/image_5.png";
        path[5] = "images/image_6.png";   

        function swapImage() 
        { 
            document.slide.src = path[i]; 
            if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
            else i = 0; 
            setTimeout("swapImage()",3000); 
        } 
        window.onload=swapImage; 
    </script>           
    <img alt="" name="slide" height="140" src="images/image_1.png" width="224" class="auto-style2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: http://www.baprinterservice.com/temp.html  It's there because it isn't quite ready a you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have **"/"** in front of your folder name.

Give path as

```
path[0] = "/images/image_1.png"; 
path[1] = "/images/image_2.png"; 
path[2] = "/images/image_3.png";
path[3] = "/images/image_4.png";
path[4] = "/images/image_5.png";
path[5] = "/images/image_6.png";
```

Comment: Jeez, I must look pretty daft. Such simple issues. I guess I shouldn't have assumed it wasn't a path issue since there were no errors.

Comment: The images at your site is at the location www.baprinterservice.com/images/image_1.png and so on. So in this case you need to have "/" in front of your folder name. :)

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

1. check your folder Case. In Unix image != Image
2. check the folder permission, folder should be access-able by all.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code working. Try this instead:

<kbd>[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AEsFL/2/)</kbd>

```
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = "images/image_1.png"; 
path[1] = "images/image_2.png"; 
path[2] = "images/image_3.png";
path[3] = "images/image_4.png";
path[4] = "images/image_5.png";
path[5] = "images/image_6.png";   

function swapImage()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("slide");
    img.src = path[i];
    i++;

    if(i >= path.length){
        i = 0;
    } 
    setTimeout(function() { swapImage() }, 3000);
}

window.onload=swapImage();
```